# os.system commands in python script causing errors

Tags: python, linux, terminal, subprocess, sleep

I have been having problems with a line of code, and just found a second interesting problem.

I have a command then when put into terminal will start a program, and then write the output to an output file. Thusfar I have been unable to get the data written to an output file for some reason (although the program starts, and I can watch it spitting out data when I have python open terminal and run it)

For some reason it seems it does not want to redirect my data to an output file. I have tried both doing it in the script, as well as in terminal (python script.py > output.out)

Now I tried starting up a sleep command before the main command, and I get an error from sleep

```
sleep: invalid option -- 'n'
```

here is the code

```
os.system('gnome-terminal -e "sleep 10 ; /usr/local/bin/mpirun -np 4 /home/mike/bin/Linux-ifort_XE_openmpi-1.6_emt64/v2_0_1/Pcrystal </dev/null &> mgo.out &"')
```

Comment: Remember to accept answers to your questions, I noticed that you haven't accepted any answers for your 6 questions

Comment: The Python docs recommend using the subprocess module instead.  You should read up on it. Also, you have several levels of subprocesses being launched (one each for `os.system`, `gnome-terminal`, and the quoted command line run inside `gnome-terminal`).  At first glance I'd say the semicolon isn't being handled by `gnome-terminal` and the `-n` option is being seen by the `sleep` command.

Comment: I understand. I have tried that to no success. The reason I tried the gnome-terminal part is to see if the Pcrystal program actually starts up, which it does. However for some reason it is having an issue redirecting the output, which is my main concern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your original problem, (without the sleep), your output redirection needs some work, try:

```
/usr/local/bin/mpirun -np 4 /home/mike/bin/Linux-ifort_XE_openmpi-1.6_emt64/v2_0_1/Pcrystal </dev/null > mgo.out 2>&1 &
```

will direct both standard output and standard error to the file.

Comment: Have you tried the above on the command line? And without the final &

Comment: Yes, the command works on the command line but does not work when called in the python script. The Pcrystal program still runs and generates all of its necessary files, and I can watch it running when terminal opens (which is why I orginally added the gnome-terminal part). However it is not redirecting the output to a file. I was wondering if maybe it has something to do with the buffer that is for some reason not redirecting the output quick enough?

Comment: Solved it! Taking out the gnome-terminal bit and just putting os.system and then your line worked. Thank you!

Comment: Good to hear and glad to have helped!